# Creating and using widgets (Scale) in Tkinter using for-loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently facing the problem of creating many (over 20) scales in Tkinter and naturally I am trying not to create and use them "manually".
Creating works just fine:

```
for ii in range(0,25):
  nam='input_a' + str(ii)
  nam = Scale(master, from_=100, to=0, orient=VERTICAL)
  nam.grid(row=0, column=2+ii)
```

Problem occurs when I am trying to get the values:

```
import numpy as np

def Aux():
  a=np.zeros(25)
  for ii in range(0,25):
    nam='input_a'+str(ii)
    a[ii]=nam.get()
  return a
```

The problem: `nam` is still a str-object, therefore it couldn't have an attribute `get`.

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the references to your Scales in a list

```
nam = []
for ii in range(0,25):
  nam.append(Scale(master, from_=100, to=0, orient=VERTICAL))
  nam[-1].grid(row=0, column=2+ii)
```

You can then use `nam[ii].get()`

Answer (score 1):

I find that a dictionary is very convenient for storing widgets, though a list will do just as nicely if you only want to access them by an integer index:

```
scales = {}
for ii in range(0,25):
    scales[ii] = Scale(...)
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I need only integer reference so the list using solution is smarter for me, but I certainly will use yours on occasion.